# show all the posts thumbnails

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, shortcode

I want to display all the posts by the featured image of each post.

Is there a shortcode or can you give me some tips on how to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you referring to? Something like a [grid theme](http://fthrwght.com/autofocus/prodemo/)?

Comment: yes, something like this, I want to be able to display all my posts as thumbnails and when a user clicks on it to go directly to that specific post

Answer (score 1):

you can modify or create a simple posts loop with only feature image in there. 
so you could use something like :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="feature-image">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

then your CSS can be:

```
.feature-image {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    }

.feature-image a:link img {
    background: green;
    padding: 3px;
    }

.feature-image a:hover img {
    background:blue;
    }
```

this should create a simple grid of feature images with a green border that will change to blue when you hover the image. obviously you can change the look of it by adding different styling but this should get you a good start point.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any ideea how to modify the thumbnail size of the featured image ?

Comment: That's both a separate question, and one that has been asked many times here on WPSE. Try searching the site for the answer. Hint: [**`add_image_size()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) is your friend.

Comment: @CristoceaCostel or you can use parameters to change the default: 
 `the_post_thumbnail(array(100,80))` 
where 100 and 80 are width an height in pixels.